# How to change Linux context-switch frequency?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, process

How is it possible to change the Linux (linaro, ubuntu, debian) context-switch frequency?

I am okay for trading-off a less-responsive system for a more efficient one.

EDIT1: I have a main process which I want to run as fast as possible (maximal clock cycles  per second), so I thought of reducing the context-switch frequency (=increasing the timeslice). The question is how to do it, and would there be a significant effect. Can I calculate the cost of the context switch? Meaning, can I estimate if I increase the timeslice by two, what will my performance gain be in % for the main process I care about?

Comment: I'd expect the effect of this setting to be minimal, and relevant only if you have more processes running than CPU cores. If no other tasks are waiting for a particular CPU, there is no need to even set up a short-time task switch timer at all, because anything that could make another task runnable would be a system call or a hardware interrupt, both of which would return the CPU to the kernel.

Comment: Sorry to be daft here, but could someone explain what 'context-switch frequency' means in the context of this question?

Comment: @sourcejedi see my EDIT1 - can I estimate the throughput improvement in % when I reduce the context switch frequency?

Comment: @NadavB I have edited my answer accordingly.  Specific measurements are best when optimizing. You don't have to treat it as black box though, for example you can use perf to measure cache misses if your CPU is good. AIUI, various types of CPU cache miss (including TLB miss) are the most important individual costs of context switching.

Answer (score 18):

If your task is the *only* process requesting time on a specific CPU, there will be no context switches between tasks :-).  But the CPU may still be interrupted, causing a context switch into the kernel and back.  And one possible cause is the pre-emption timer, checking if there is another task to run on this CPU...

Linux *can* avoid generating any pre-emption timer interrupts on the cpu when there will be no reason to do so.  See `CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL`.  To use this feature, it must be enabled when the kernel was built, *and* it must be enabled using a boot option.

- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/timers/NO_HZ.txt
- https://lwn.net/Articles/549580/ "(Nearly) full tickless operation in 3.10"

> By default, no CPU will be an adaptive-ticks CPU.  The "nohz_full="
>   boot parameter specifies the adaptive-ticks CPUs.  For example,
>   "nohz_full=1,6-8" says that CPUs 1, 6, 7, and 8 are to be adaptive-ticks
>   CPUs.  Note that you are prohibited from marking all of the CPUs as
>   adaptive-tick CPUs [...]

LWN.net says "according to Ingo Molnar, as much as 1% of the CPU's time will be saved" for adaptive-ticks CPUs.  The kernel document says this has six different costs, and there is also a list of "KNOWN ISSUES".

This gain is relatively small, particularly compared to the potential throughput gains of reducing the frequency of context-switches between multiple tasks, as referenced in this answer: [How to change the length of time-slices used by the Linux CPU scheduler?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466722/how-to-change-the-length-of-time-slices-used-by-the-linux-cpu-scheduler/466723#466723)

Small print: these measurements pre-date Spectre, Meltdown, KPTI and x86 ASID support :-(.  And I guess they also apply to somewhat older hardware.  Ask a kernel expert or run your own measurements on how the cost of context-switches has changed on your specific kernel version and hardware... PTI was largely supposed to be mitigated by ASID, except for software that calls into the kernel very frequently, the main example being databases.  But I don't have a good grasp on the numbers.

Molnar's hope in the original RFC patch was that with time, it "will likely be enabled by most Linux distros".  I notice Fedora 28 provides a default kernel built with `NO_HZ_FULL` support.  Debian 9 does not, however.

---

More recently, Linux v4.17 [removes a residual 1 Hz timer tick from the `nohz_full` CPUs](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/083c6eeab2cc13894618d188b854f2fc6b5b2303).  I imagine the effect on throughput is quite small :-), but I've been trying to follow the status of `NO_HZ_FULL` benefits when there are multiple runnable processes on a CPU -

> once we reach 0 Hz we can [then] remove the periodic tick assumption from
>      nr_running>=2 as well, by essentially interrupting busy tasks only as
>      frequently as the sched_latency constraints require us to do - once
>      every 4-40 msecs, depending on nr_running.

This is a bit confusing as pre-emption already started using a separate, more precise tick back in v2.6.25-rc1, [commit 8f4d37ec073c, "sched: high-res preemption tick"](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/8f4d37ec073c).  Found via this comment on the same LWN.net article: https://lwn.net/Articles/549754/ ).

Comment: what about the kernel.sched_rr_timeslice_ms ?

Comment: @NadavB if you are using realtime sched_rr tasks, say so. This is a specialist topic. If you are not, then no :-).