# No sched_min_granularity_ns in kernel parameters

Tags: scheduling, process-management

According to this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466723/118395), there are three kernel parameters for controlling process scheduler:

```
kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns
kernel.sched_latency_ns
kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns
```

However, on my system which is Ubuntu, I don't see them. Instead, the following variables exist:

```
$ sudo sysctl -A | grep sched
kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled = 1
kernel.sched_cfs_bandwidth_slice_us = 5000
kernel.sched_child_runs_first = 0
kernel.sched_deadline_period_max_us = 4194304
kernel.sched_deadline_period_min_us = 100
kernel.sched_energy_aware = 1
kernel.sched_rr_timeslice_ms = 100
kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000
kernel.sched_schedstats = 0
kernel.sched_util_clamp_max = 1024
kernel.sched_util_clamp_min = 1024
kernel.sched_util_clamp_min_rt_default = 1024
$ uname -r
5.13.0-27-generic
```

The question is, should I set them manually or they are replaced with some other variables?

Comment: If you want to change associated value and keys just exist as sysctls, why would you look for a better way than using /sbin/sysctl -w ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your comment. Problem is that those variables no longer exist in sysctl. Also, it is not `sched_min_granularity_ns`, but it is `min_granularity_ns`.

Answer (score 1):

https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/sysctl-output-changed-from-kernel-5-10-to-5-13-why/17097 says they have been moved to /sys/kernel/debug/sched

Comment: OK I see `/sys/kernel/debug/sched/min_granularity_ns`. Does that mean the correct command to change that is `sysctl min_granularity_ns=1000`? In the link it is written that sysctl no longer sees that variable. So, I wonder how to change that?

Comment: can you try something like this:  # echo 2250000 >  /sys/kernel/debug/sched/min_granularity_ns